# Issues with a tagging system using Autocomplete android

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I am trying to implement something similar to facebook's search system, where if a user starts typing in a name it brings autocomplete suggestions based on the letters typed, and with an additional option to search for more results. Each result is an object and not a string, and I have tried adding an extra result for search but every time I click on search or one of the objects a replace text occurs with the object as oppose to the name and I know it is a method of the autocomplete widget. Is there another way to go about it?

Here is my code:

```
private AutoCompleteTextView sx;

sx = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.sx);
if(sadapter == null) {
    sadapter = new Sadapter(PostActivity.this, usersFound);
    sx.setAdapter(sadapter);
}

sx.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (sx.getText().toString().length() <= 3 && sadapter != null) {
            usersFound.clear();
            sadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (sx.getText().toString().length() > 3) {
            usersFound.clear();
            sadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "Changing text " + s);
                sxname = s.toString();

            testCreate();
            sadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});

sx.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        DatabaseUser newAdd = usersFound.get(position);
        if(position ==  searchServerIndex) {
            sx.setText(sxname);
            usersFound.clear();
            sadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            apiGetPossibleCandidates();
        } else {
            sx.setText("");
        }
    }
});

private void testCreate() {
    DatabaseUser nuser1 = new DatabaseUser("userid", "pictureid", "Jon");
    DatabaseUser nuser2 = new DatabaseUser("userid", "pictureid", "Jonny");
    DatabaseUser nuser3 = new DatabaseUser("userid", "pictureid", "Jong");
    DatabaseUser nuser4 = new DatabaseUser("userid", "pictureid", "Joan");
    DatabaseUser searchServer = new DatabaseUser("SearchId", "pictureid", "Search " + sxname);

    usersFound.add(nuser1);
    usersFound.add(nuser2);
    usersFound.add(nuser3);
    usersFound.add(nuser4);
    searchServerIndex = usersFound.size();
    usersFound.add(searchServer);

    if(sadapter != null) {
        sadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is the adapter:

```
public class Sadapter extends ArrayAdapter<DatabaseUser> {

private Context mContext;
    private List<DatabaseUser> usersSearch;
    private List<DatabaseUser> usersFiltered;

    public Sadapter(Context context, List<DatabaseUser> usersAdded) {
        super(context, 0, usersAdded);
        mContext = context;
        usersSearch = usersAdded;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return usersSearch.size();
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_autosearch_item, null);
        }

        //helps for recycling
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.userTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.userTxt);

        v.setTag(holder);

            String name = usersSearch.get(position).getName();
            holder.userTxt.setText(name);


        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView userTxt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are applying filtering manually you can use `setThreaesHold(3)` method which will notify the adapter if it is more then 3 char typed in AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: I actually have setThreshold, well how do I then know to start searching for users once the threshold is met where would I have to include the code for that

Comment: Can you show the code of 
Adapter ..?

Comment: Updated the code above... also, I still have the issue that when the user clicks on a suggested result it replaces the text with the object for example  it looks like this datax.datax.database.DatabaseUser%401817753e, when I just want the string of the text

Comment: you can override getItem() method in your adapater and return the object of DataBaseUser of particular position from the searchlist.. like
`@Override
        public DatabaseUser getItem(int position) {
            return usersSearch.get(position);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

you can override getItem() method in your adapater and return the object of DataBaseUser of particular position from the searchlist.. like

```
@Override public DatabaseUser getItem(int position) { 
    return usersSearch.get(position); 
}
```

So from your onClick method you can call this method and it will give you DatabaseUser object from which you can retrive your text. I hope it helps you ..

Comment: I do not have an issue grabbing the user, the issue is the text showing up, I need to stop it from overriding what the user inputs when a user is selected? Also, if you are saying I do not need the textwatcher then that is what I wanted to see code to replace or where I would call for grabUsers when 4 characters are entered...

Comment: @Lion789: I tried using textwatcher for autocompletetextview.. It doesn't work very well.. you can override two methods of AutocompleteTextView,
protected void performFiltering(CharSequence text, int keyCode)
public void onFilterComplete(int count)

Checkout https://github.com/mobisystech/autocompletetextview/blob/master/AutoCompleteTextView/app/src/main/java/com/mobisys/android/autocompletetextview/AutoCompleteView.java

You probably can use library as well https://github.com/mobisystech/autocompletetextview